# Excel sum with multiple conditions on other tables (sumifs/sumproduct)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, sumifs, sumproduct

I am trying to use `SUMIFS` or `SUMPRODUCT` to resolve my questions, but it's still not working. I wonder how to get it.
So, the conditions are (1) if the column "fruit" matches those with the "x" on the table in the middle, and (2) the column of week also matches the ones with "x" of the table on the right, then sum it up.

Besides, the rows of the table on the left change every week, as the time goes (thus I think it should choose the whole column, instead of `A2:A37`)

Can somebody help please? Thank you very much!

[image]

In my opinion, it should be

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--A:A=IF(K:K="x",J:J,0),--B:B=if(G:G="x",F:F,0),C:C)
```

but it shows error.

And if I use sumfis with xlookup, then it only outputs the first one it matches, not all the data, so it's also wrong.

| Fruit | Yes |
| --- | --- |
| mango | x |
| banana |  |
| apple | x |
| papaya |  |
| melon | x |

| Week | Yes |
| --- | --- |
| 14 |  |
| 15 |  |
| 16 | x |
| 17 |  |
| 18 |  |
| 19 |  |
| 20 |  |
| 21 | x |
| 22 | x |
| 23 |  |
| 24 |  |
| 25 |  |
| 26 | x |
| 27 |  |
| 28 |  |
| 29 | x |
| 30 |  |
| 31 |  |
| 32 |  |
| 33 |  |
| 34 |  |
| 35 |  |
| 36 |  |
| 37 | x |
| 38 | x |
| 39 |  |
| 40 |  |
| 41 | x |
| 42 |  |
| 43 |  |
| 44 |  |
| 45 | x |
| 46 |  |
| 47 |  |
| 48 |  |
| 49 |  |

| Week | Fruit | Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | mango | 1 |
| 15 | mango | 2 |
| 16 | melon | 3 |
| 16 | banana | 1 |
| 16 | papaya | 2 |
| 19 | melon | 3 |
| 20 | papaya | 1 |
| 21 | banana | 2 |
| 22 | banana | 3 |
| 23 | banana | 1 |
| 24 | banana | 2 |
| 25 | banana | 3 |
| 26 | banana | 2 |
| 27 | apple | 2 |
| 28 | melon | 2 |
| 29 | apple | 3 |
| 29 | melon | 3 |
| 29 | apple | 3 |
| 29 | apple | 3 |
| 33 | papaya | 3 |
| 34 | apple | 3 |
| 35 | melon | 3 |
| 36 | apple | 3 |
| 37 | papaya | 3 |
| 38 | apple | 3 |
| 39 | mango | 3 |
| 40 | banana | 3 |
| 41 | banana | 3 |
| 42 | apple | 3 |
| 43 | apple | 3 |
| 44 | apple | 3 |
| 45 | apple | 3 |
| 46 | papaya | 3 |
| 47 | apple | 4 |
| 48 | apple | 4 |
| 49 | apple | 4 |

Comment: I assume you may need `FILTER()` function. What is your excel version?

Comment: My version is 2306

Comment: Version 2306 is `MS365 Version 2306 (Build 16529.20010, Build 16529.20064, Build 16529.20126, Build 16529.20146)` released on `June 05` , `June 12`, `June 21` and `June 23` so what is the build of your version 2306

Comment: Power Query would handle this with ease.

Comment: Hello, the build is 16529.20226

Comment: So you have an updated version. Released after `June 23`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C2:C14,(IFNA(MATCH(B2:B14,FILTER(F:F,G:G="x"),0),0)*(IFNA(MATCH(A2:A14,FILTER(J:J,K:K="x"),0),0)))))
```

Result:

[image]

Don't forget to adapt ranges as needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I use the whole column as =SUM(FILTER(C:C,(IFNA(MATCH(B:B,FILTER(F:F,G:G="x"),0),0)*(IFNA(MATCH(A:A,FILTER(J:J,K:K="x"),0),0))))) and then I got the result 19,923077. All of my numbers are whole numbers, I don't understand why there is decimal in my answer.

Comment: Can't explain this behavior. With sample data you provided it returns 21 for me.

Comment: You are right. I recheck and then found that they are not integers. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of using <kbd>XMATCH( )</kbd>, <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd>, <kbd>IFS( )</kbd> & <kbd>SUM( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>M2</kbd>

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(
     XMATCH(B2:B37,TOCOL(IFS(G:G="x",F:F),3))*
     XMATCH(A2:A37,TOCOL(IFS(K:K="x",J:J),3)))*
 C2:C37)
```

---

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. It seems that my version (2306/16529.20226) does not support tocol (I could not find this formula in my excel)

Comment: @ECZZ what you are saying as per **`MS Documentation`** it supports from `2208(Build 15601)` version onwards. **[here read](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/tocol-function-22839d9b-0b55-4fc1-b4e6-2761f8f122ed#Availability)**